# How to find prevoius select2 selected index

Tags: jquery, find

I have select2 elements added dynamically through ajax call. In specific circumstances when value of select2 i change i have to get selected index of previous select 2 and assign it to hidden field value.
The code is:

```
$("#category_selects").on("change", "[id^='category_select_']", function(e) {
    alert("you selected :" + $(this).val());
    if($(this).val() === 'na'){
        console.log($(this).prev());
    }
    else{
        $("#categoryId").val($(this).val());
    }
```

But console.log($(this).prev()) is not giving the previous selected select2 index.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better that you store the previous value and use it later to display in alert.

HTML :

```
<select id="fruit">
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="mango">mango</option>
    <option value="grape">grape</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var previous;

$("#fruit").focus(function(){
    previous = $(this).val();
});

$("#fruit").change(function(){
    alert(previous);
    previous = $(this).val();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/x5PKf/1144/